# How quickly should I respond to answers I receive?

Tags: discussion, answers, feedback

When getting answers I like to take my time to digest them in a proper manner. Usually, despite being able to reply instantly, I prefer to go home, think a bit about the problem and wait until the next day to reply. Sometimes I feel that is a bit "frowned upon" by my peers.

Where does the community stand on this matter?

**Should we give people who answer feedback as soon as possible or is perfectly ok to wait a couple of days before getting back to them?**

Comment: I think it's more *common* to give fast feedback, but I don't think it should be *frowned upon* if someone prefers to take his time. Some people may jump to the conclusion that you're not giving *any* feedback, but they are wrong and should learn some patience.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's not bad to answer to the answer later - I think it's very good idea, because to reply without actually testing it isn't good practice. Additionally, it's your time and your choice what would you do at what time.

I'm getting accepted/commented after a month or so..

Comment: I agree totally. Pick your time, go through the answers. It helps nobody if you rush and choose an answer because you think it might work. Go through all answers, test them, think about them, provide additional information if necessary and then act upon them.

Comment: @genesis-φ on the spirit of the discussion took my time to get back to you. I agree and, by the number of upvotes you had, seams that it's common sense that replies should be given at one's own pace. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, it depends on the answer. If it contains absolute code that you have to take and test then it's totally fine to wait until you're done testing before posting any comment. Comment like "thanks, I'll test it and get back to you" is possible, but not necessary.

If the answer is something you're not sure about or don't fully understand, I think it's better to say so in fast comment and ask the person posting the answer for more details, better ask this while it's still fresh in his/her mind.

Comment: `<snarky>` You should always make sure that you understand the *code* that someone posts, too, rather than simply copying and pasting it into your IDE.

Comment: Yep that can fall under "something you're not sure about or don't fully understand" :)

Answer (score 2):

Remember that questions on Stack Overflow are meant to help not only the OP, but all people who might find the question from web searches in the future.

It's therefore perfectly fine, even preferable to take your time and write a good solid answer. However, there is still value in helping the OP solve his problem quickly, so it's fine to provide a quick answer first and then follow up with the in depth explanation when you have time.

**EDIT**: I just realized you were asking this from the *asker*'s perspective, but the point still stands: This site is meant to help more people than just the OP. In fact questions that are specific to one person get closed as "too localized".

It's perfectly fine to take the time to wait a few days for a good solid answer that will help future visitors before accepting, although a quick answer might have been all you needed to get past the problem.

You can still reward the quick answer with an upvote and possibly a comment.

Comment: I think he meant that he asks a question, receives answers and then takes his time to go through them.

Answer (score 2):

As much as I would like to give quick comments on answers and replies to comments it is not always ideal/possible. I have a currently open question on SU where I replied quickly as I was still on the site but it will take me time to gather more information before I can edit the question. I have slept, gone to work, and will get home before I can add more detail. It would be nice if we could all reply instantanly but life, unfortunately, gets in the way.